# Rejecting Strings with a space between two words

Tags: python

So I've almost finished a program in which the user inputs a name/word and it spits out the Soundex counterpart.
The code runs well and the Soundex methodology is sound, "Get it Sound". What I had issues with were the strings being returned. Things like space before or after the word typed in or having an uppercase and lowercase name being repeated when they shouldn't have been. Those got fixed rather easily.

What I'm having issues with now is when the user inputs something like, "Carl Sagan" it returns the ("Word should only contain characters") elif of my program.

What I'd like to do is respond to the user and say, ("Two words entered at once, Please enter one at a time."). When those instances happen.

Here's  a snippet of my code:

```py
#input name

name = input("To start, Please give your name :")
print("\nGreetings,", name.strip().capitalize(), "Your Soundex-name is:", convert_to_soundex(name), "\n" )

#creating dictionary
dicti={}

#convert name to code and store in dictionary
dicti[name]=convert_to_soundex(name)

# keeping asking user for a word or name until user enters 0
while(True):
    
    word=input("Please give a word to convert (0 to exit) :").strip().capitalize()
    if word=='0':
        break
    
    elif word=="":
        print("Please give word with atleast one character.")
        
    elif not word.isalpha():
        print("Word should only contain characters.")
        
    else:
        if word in dicti:
            print("Word already exists")
            
        else:
            dicti[word]=convert_to_soundex(word)
            
#printing formatted data
printData(dicti)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add another `while..if` instead of `name` input like this:

```
while True:
  name = input("To start, Please give your name :")
  if ' ' in name:
    print("Two words entered at once, Please enter one at a time.")
  else:
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#input name

name = input("To start, Please give your name :")
print("\nGreetings,", name.strip().capitalize(), "Your Soundex-name is:", convert_to_soundex(name), "\n" )

#creating dictionary
dicti={}

#convert name to code and store in dictionary
dicti[name]=convert_to_soundex(name)

# keeping asking user for a word or name until user enters 0
while(True):
    
    word=input("Please give a word to convert (0 to exit) :").strip().capitalize()
    if word=='0':
        break

    elif ' ' in word:
        print("Two words entered at once, Please enter one at a time.")
        
    elif word=="":
        print("Please give word with atleast one character.")
        
    elif not word.isalpha():
        print("Word should only contain characters.")
        
    else:
        if word in dicti:
            print("Word already exists")
            
        else:
            dicti[word]=convert_to_soundex(word)
            
#printing formatted data
printData(dicti)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
name = input("give name please...")

for nam in name:
    if nam == " ":
        print('invalid input')
        

# removes space from input
print(''.join([i for i in name if i != " "]))
```